# How to use autoplay partly in reveal.js?

Tags: javascript, reveal.js

In a section with fragments i want to use autoplay for the fragments only.

```
....
<section id="fragments">
<h2>Things</h2>
   <p>...</p>
   <div style="text-align: left; margin-left: 30%">
   <p class="fragment"><i class="fa fa-long-arrow-right"></i> issue 1</p>
   <p class="fragment"><i class="fa fa-long-arrow-right"></i> issue 2</p>
   <p class="fragment"><i class="fa fa-long-arrow-right"></i> issue 3</p>
   <p class="fragment"><i class="fa fa-long-arrow-right"></i> issue 4</p>
   </div>
   <aside class="notes">
       This slide has fragments which are also stepped through in the notes window.
   </aside>
</section>
...
```

How to autoplay the fragments?

Answer (score 0):

By setting the attribute `data-autoslide=milliseconds` in the section

```
...
<section id="fragments" data-autoslide="1000">
...
```

the autoplay works for the fragments, but this autoplays to the next section.
See http://codepen.io/tstangenberg/pen/OMGmbm